# Scala singleton objects and implicit resolution

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

What is the best way to make implicit resolution in scala work with singleton objects? This is especially common with `Either` and custom error objects.

In the code example below a method returns an application-specific error wrapped in IO. The error is represented by a singleton object extending `Throwable`. This code does not compile because scala is looking for an implicit for `AppSpecificError.type` instead of `Throwable`.

It is possible to put everything into variables with a specified type but it looks weird. This seems like a pretty common case, what is the best way to address it?

```scala
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._

import scala.util.Random

object EitherTest {

  case object AppSpecificError extends Throwable

  def random: IO[Boolean] = {
    IO(Random.nextBoolean())
  }

  def appMethod(flag: Boolean): EitherT[IO, Throwable, Int] = {
    for {
      flag <- EitherT.right(random)
      result <- if (flag) {
        EitherT.left[Int](AppSpecificError.pure[IO]) // compilation error here
      } else {
        EitherT.right[Throwable](10.pure[IO])
      }
      // can be more computations here
    } yield result
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    appMethod(true).value.unsafeRunSync() match {
      case Right(s) => println("Success")
      case Left(error) => println(error)
    }
  }
}
```

```
Error:(18, 14) type mismatch;
 found   : cats.data.EitherT[cats.effect.IO,_1,Int] where type _1 >: EitherTest.AppSpecificError.type <: Throwable
 required: cats.data.EitherT[cats.effect.IO,Throwable,Int]
Note: _1 <: Throwable, but class EitherT is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
      result <- if (flag) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to specify type parameters explicitly

```
EitherT.left[Int][IO, Throwable](AppSpecificError.pure[IO])
```

or use type ascription

```
EitherT.left[Int]((AppSpecificError: Throwable).pure[IO])
```